# python suds urllib2 Error

Tags: python, web-services, urllib2, suds

Suds was working fine in an Ubuntu VM. I cloned this VM and am now running it in a different environment. But now its throwing this error:

```
ERROR: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../keystone/keystone/bin/keystone-manage", line 16, in <module>
    keystone.manage.main()
  File "../keystone/keystone/keystone/manage/__init__.py", line 284, in main
    raise exc
 urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
```

Does this have something to do with urllib2 and proxies?

Thanks in advance!

,
K

Comment: It worked!!!!! When I added the DNS servers to /etc/resolv.conf.

Comment: Dont know why urllib2 needs DNS and wget does not.

Comment: Not Python's fault; in cloning it, you probably messed up the network interfaces so that there was a clash and some hardware or software somewhere didn't like it.